# c# way to read folder/files using backup operators "rights"

Tags: c#, file-permissions, ntfs, ownership

I have to read all data on a local system and the mapped CIFS shares.  I can use shadowcopy to avoid active files but I have issues with not having permission for "home" folders.  I am local admin AND in the *backup operators* group.  I have to to test on domain joined, non domain joined and azure domain joined windows 10 systems.
My understanding of the *backup operators* role is that it bypasses file/folder permission to allow read access for purposes of backing up data.
When I try to run a simple console app and:

```
DirectoryInfo directoryInformation = new DirectoryInfo(path);
List<Tuple<string, DateTime>> fileList = new List<Tuple<string, DateTime>>();
foreach (FileInfo file in directoryInformation.GetFiles())
{
  fileList.Add(new Tuple<string, DateTime>(file.FullName, file.LastWriteTimeUtc));
  Console.WriteLine("Found:" + file.FullName);
}
```

I get "access to the path d:\foldername is denied" when on the .GetFiles() command.
Which is accurate for normal users.  Since I removed all access to that folder to test aside form one other user.

I am asking how I can use the Backup Operators role to access the folder/files in C#?

Do I have to make a service that logs in with a user in the backup operators role and send the request to it?  I don't see how that is different than running a console app with the same user.

I am in .NET Framework 4.5.2
I have searched around but cannot find examples where backup operators role was used to gain access to files in c#.  I know of the SecureCopy tool that will allow you to use this role to gain access to files that the running user can't see, so I know it can be done.

Suggestions?

Comment: running a service with the "correct" user can be a solution. There are some other method allowing your application to impersonate a different user, but as far as I know, not a "build in" user (i.e., you have to know username and password of the user you are impersonating).
A service sounds the safer road to me

Comment: I am already running the app with a user in the backup operators group.  I think I need to change the current process to enable SeBackupPrivilege.  Any ideas how?

Comment: If you login with the user you are using for you application, can you browse that folder ? I mean with Explorer (not internet explorer). It sounds to me that your user cannot access that folder

Comment: Correct the running user does not have direct access to the folder with explorer.  However that same user is in the backup operators role and owns the root folders. while if invoked properly will give them access via code (not explorer). I am asking for an example on how to do that. I think the files need to be opened the files with FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS set. ? Anyone?